# How to get form field array in play framework

Tags: groovy, playframework

I'm using groovy to render templates in Play framework. I have a checkbox inside a list loop:

```
<input type="checkbox" name="chkUser[]" id="chkUser{users.getId()}" value="${users.getId()}">
```

How can i get the state of the checkbox array in Controller page.

Comment: You set a value on a checkbox?

Comment: Are you sure this code is correct? Your name and value attribute seem... "wrong" in a checkbox

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It can be achieved using hidden fields for every checkbox.

```
<input type="hidden" name="HdChkUser${users.getId()}">
<input type="checkbox" name="ChkUser${users.getId()}">
```

If the state of the checkbox changes then updating the hidden field value. Which can be used in for msubmission.

Answer (score 3):

Came across this a couple of monthes ago. It seems you can use find those back in controller using :

```
public static myFormFunction(boolean[] chkUser) {
...
```

Not sure of it and I cannot check this right now. 
Take a look at the [official documentation](http://www.playframework.org/documentation/1.0/controllers#Arraysorcollectionsofsupportedtypes).

Comment: that was useful but how to check the state of the checkbox whether checked or not checked

Comment: I'm getting only checked checkbox values but i want all the checkboxes status

Comment: As said in the HTML specification, "inputs with no value are not posted".

Comment: i have a function update(userId,status) In this function userId will be chkUser[i], if the chekbox is selected then status will be 1 if not selected then 0. so if there are 20 users then i will update for 20 users